# How do I determine resistivity from electron defects of high purity gold?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, scattering, electrical-resistance, phonons

I am trying to create a plot for the electrical resistivity of high purity gold from 1 K to 1000 K. I found gold's resistivity at 300 K using the Wiedemann-Franz Law based on thermal conductivity data I was provided. I also have a table that has the resistivity of gold at 295 K By Mathiessen's rule, the resistivity is $$r_e=r_{e-ph} +r_{e-d}$$ and I can find $r_{e-ph}$ at each temperature using Bloch's formula $$r_{e-ph}=4 r_0 (\frac{T}{\Theta_D})^5  \int_0^{\frac{\theta_D}{T}}\frac{x^5e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} \,dx $$

I figured I could solve for $r_0$ using the resistivity value at 295 K from the table. The I could solve for $r_{e-ph}$ at all the temperatures using Bloch's formula. The only thing I don't know how to determine is the $r_{e-d}$. When I don't account for the defects, I get the shape I am supposed to get, but the values at the low temperature region are way too low because that is where the defects dominate. Any help would be appreciated. The only other data I have is the electron scattering rate at each temperature since I have the thermal conductivity at each temperature.